# Google cloud free trial billing account closed after 1 week with balance remaining

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, google-console-developer

I signed up for google cloud and recieved 300$ free trial. Recently I **wasn't able to ssh** into my instance. So I checked the google cloud console and found a message showing you must **Enable billing** to use further. 
Now I **can't associate my project with the free trial account** which has 285$ and 45 days remaining.[Also the number of days left has drastically reduced from 55 to 45 after this]. When I look into the free account it shows closed.

Comment: @DDR have you solved your question? Let us know if you got any news about it. Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The free trial account was suspended. Reason - "Unfortunately, we were unable to **verify billing instrument** ownership using the documents you submitted" says Google.

**Solution**

Go to: https://support.google.com/payments/contact/verify

Submit **Government-issued identification** and **proof of ownership of billing instrument**.
 The verfication process typically takes less than 24 hours, but, in rare cases, may take a few days

Comment: And did your verification get accepted? I submitted, but they still rejected it.

Answer (score 1):

For issues like this it's best to contact Google Cloud Support directly. All projects have free access to [Billing Support](https://support.google.com/cloud/contact/cloud_billing_internal?rd=1). During the free trial, you can also access technical support using the [Free Trial Troubleshooter](https://support.google.com/cloud/troubleshooter/6275061).

For more info see also '[Get support](https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/6282346?hl=en#gcp)' and '[Support during the free trial](https://cloud.google.com/free-trial/docs/support-during-free-trial)'.